# Unsolved redefinition of module 'firebase' error

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am creating my own Push Notification-only app called "Next_Tremity Push Notification Live". It's designed for people can receive Notifications about my previously App Store-approved gift stickers apps, my referral links, my new devices, and my own other things.[image]

Help me by giving me solution(s) to resolve "redefinition of module 'firebase'" error and all other errors!

I had to use pods and Google Firebase for my own Push Notification-only app. I decided to develop my own Push Notification-only app and fixed some errors by found solutions on Google Search.

After my "Framework not found Pods_Next_Tremity_Push_Notification_Live" error was resolved, my app was worked fine on my spare iPhone 13 mini. I tried achieving for App Store publish and getting an error! Also, I got other errors after I tried to resolve an achieve error.

I had to use pods and Google Firebase for my own Push Notification-only app. I decided to develop my own Push Notification-only app and fixed some errors by found solutions on Google Search.

I used Xcode 14.3 to develop my own Push Notification-only app on my M1 Max MacBook Pro 16". It's running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 at this time.

I tried clean build, clean derived data, pods uninstall/install, removed Google Firebase package, and added the same package again.